# How to generate index for datastore entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, app-engine-ndb, gql

Previously, I have `EmailQueue` NDB model which had indexed property:

```
class EmailQueue(ndb.Model):
    ...
    sent_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=False)
    updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True, indexed=False)
```

then, I removed that `indexed=False` parameter. Now index is created:

[image: DataStore indexes]

But looking at Index Entry Count (which 19), I think it is created just for new entries (total number of entries is 1432).

I haven't touched **index.yaml**, but it contains the following record:

```
- kind: EmailQueue
  properties:
  - name: email_type
  - name: status
  - name: sent_date
```

Is there any way to generate it for remaining entries? Without this my queries (like `SELECT * FROM EmailQueue WHERE email_type=3 and status=1 and sent_date<DATETIME('2014-06-02 00:00:00') and sent_date>=DATETIME('2014-05-26 00:00:00')`) return wrong results.

Upd. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23426704/604388) says that I should update each entry manually. But it will affect my `updated` value. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: You have to fetch each item and put() every record.

Comment: If you don't want to affect the updated value, change the model for the duration of the run.  If you only have a couple of thousand entities, do the update via the remote_api shell and then you don't have to deploy any code.

Comment: @TimHoffman, thanks. How the update can look like? Just get and `put()`?

Comment: Yep.  do a keys only query, fetch in batches with ndb.get_multi then ndb.put_multi will probably be the quickest.  I use remote api a lot and it's always quicker to do things in batches to cut down on the round trip for each get/put operation

Comment: @TimHoffman, hmm, I do `e = models.EmailQueue.query(), e = e.fetch(keys_only=True)` (thru remote api) and it fails with `OverQuotaError` (Datastore Small Operations), which looks strange with just ~1500 entries.

Comment: Not really, lots of remote api calls do add up.  I suggest you enable billing.  How many items are you fetching at a time ?

Comment: @TimHoffman, all items, see the code in the previous comment, it doesn't have any limit.

Comment: Ok this is where ndb differs from db.  I don't use fetch with ndb. The limit arg just limits the total number retrieved.  In db that was effectively a batch size explicitly.  With ndb you can specify a batch size. Under the hood ndb performs a sequence of async operations with the default batch size.  By default the batch size is 20.  Have a look at the docs for ndb query, and you can see the reference to batchsize and how you can change it - See query options.  I would up the batch size significantly. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_fetch

Comment: That's interesting - when I do `fetch(500)` (which is almost half of the number of entries I have), it almost does not increase number of used Datastore Read Operations, but when I do `fetch()` it quickly becomes over quota.

Comment: Thats a fair number of rpcs.  Try it again with a bigger batch size.  Also if you don't have billing enabled you are rate limited with some rpc operations.  You said the over quota before was (Datastore Small Operations),  some quotas are for the day, other of for small periods.  You may be hitting both now if you don't have billing enabled.  I have in the past run remoate_api jobs for 24 hours straight, manipulating a couple of hundred thousand entities.

Comment: If you are running over quota then push the code and run it from via a task.